# WebSphere local transaction containment boundary issue J2CA0086W

Tags: jdbc, websphere, jta

In WebSphere, if you code opens two concurrent database connections, you get an error of the form:

J2CA0086W: Shareable connection MCWrapper id 556e556e  Managed connection WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@52365236  State:STATE_TRAN_WRAPPER_INUSE
 from resource jdbc/abc was used within a local transaction containment boundary.

Our framework allows us to do so (nested transactions which can be on a separate connection or multiple named transactions). I've seen lots of references to turning off some switch in WebSphere to turn on connection sharing but no details on how to set this flag. Can someone point me to the steps to achieve this?

Specifically, if you see this article: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSEQTP&dc=DB520&dc=D600&dc=DB530&dc=D700&dc=DB500&dc=DB540&dc=DB510&dc=DB550&q1=j2ca0086w&uid=swg21121449&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

under "Resolving the problem" I want to know how to set the connection pool to be unshareable (assuming that indeed solves the problem).

Comment: ok, <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope> sets the datasource as unshareable, except when accessing via Hibernate/JPA, I continue to get the same error (as if WebSphere was treating the connection as shareable).

Comment: Found out the root cause is the fact that because J2EE 2.0 didn't mention what the container's behavior should be when not using global transactions, WebSphere introduced "Local Transaction Containment" and imposed this requirement that within a servlet call (in our case), you cannot have a thread have two physical database connections. Bummer!

Comment: I guess I'll run from WebSphere next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of IBM WAS are you using? If you have WAS 8, go to
Resources-> JDC-> Datasources-> your datasources -> WebSphere Application Server properties -> Datasources no transactional.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

The message happens when `dataSource.getConnection()` is called twice in
a servlet. The datasource jdbc/oracle is lookup from local reference.
Call it once and reuse the connection or call `con.close()` before doing the 2nd `getConnection()`

Comment: if we get the StatelessSession from the injected sessionFactory does it create (open) another connection for us? I'm getting same error whenever I'm trying to do so and my dataSource in WAS is a transactional

Comment: It seems like it does not create a new connection when a connection already opened @Vahid